# Left Right Sidebar + tabbarController (IOS Objectivec)

Tags: ios, objective-c

Below is flow i want Loginvc->tabbarvcontroller(4tab)(also with left-right sidebar)

[image]

My problem is

I want to do
1)after login hide backbar button + add left right sidebar + tabbarcontroller

But when i implement backbarbutton is not hide and it load tabbarcontroller page instead of tab1.

Thanks inadvance

Comment: did you push to tabvieecontroller after login ?

Comment: After login tabbarcontroller should be your root view.

Comment: @KKRocks 1) yes pushing tabviewcontroller after login

Comment: @HarvantS. yes after login tabbarviewcontroller is my rootviewcontroller

Comment: ok then you need to set tabViewController as rootViewController . and check my answer .

Comment: @NiravZalavadia My bad. I misread your question. Login VC and TabBar VC should have own navigation controllers. You can manage things much better in this case. Don't push or present TabBar Navigation. Instead remove your Login VC (Navigation Controller too) from hierarchy and set up TabBar VC with navigation controller to windows root view.

Comment: @NiravZalavadia comment updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this steps :

```
1. set TabViewControllerID  in storyboard . and then set tabbarView controller as rootviewcontroller of app delegate using app delegate object after successful login.


 UITabBarController * tabBarController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabbarControllerID"];
 AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 appDelegate.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;

2 . Add left bar button in your tabViewController’s Viewcontroller .

3. and use MFSideMenu third party library for left and right menu.
```

for library : https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but i tried ur solution but found no luck problem 1)How to assign two rootviewcontroller one for tabbarcontroller and another sidebar 2) if i remove sidebar and alone tabbar on window also create issue when i am pressing tabs it will cause out of bounds issue.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
UIStoryboard*Storyboard=[AppDelegate storyBoardType];

    tbTBC *tabvc=(tbTBC*)[Storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tbTBCId"];
    NSLog(@"tabvc controller ===>%@",tabvc.viewControllers);
    tabvc.selectedIndex=3;//set tabbar index number to push on that particular tab bar


    [self.revealViewController setFrontViewController:tabvc];
    [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
```